# How to create SQL Server 2012 database with C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, database

I'm creating a system using SQL Server 2012 for database, but when this system is starting first time in a computer, I want the system create the database and tables for me no create this manual.

How to I create database with C#? And how to I set connect string? because normally I set database name in the connect string, but now, I need create database before

Comment: Too broad. Close-voting. Check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937685.aspx)

Comment: Use EntityFrameWork codefirst

Comment: How are you distributing the program, Are you using an installer, click-once, or are you just copying the compiled exe to the computer? Also how are you accessing the database, if you are using EntityFramework it has things built in to create the database for you but if you are just using ADO.net you may need a setup script.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I wanted just copying the compiled exe to the computer

Comment: @RaimondKuipers I will study about this, thank you so much

Comment: @HighCore I don't have idea for how to do this, but I thought for do this with just SQL and SqlCommand class, if it is possible, because I don't know other solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use SQL script, leave database name empty. Example code here :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  using (var conn = new SqlConnection("data source=DBServer; uid=UserName; pwd=Password;"))
  {
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
      conn.Open();
      cmd.Connection = conn;
      cmd.CommandText = "Create Database NewDB;";
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      cmd.CommandText = "Use NewDB;CREATE TABLE dbo.Table1 (ID int, Data nvarchar(128));";
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had try it, but it's not working, I had change DBServer for localhost, uid=sa; pwd=admin, but it's not working

Comment: You cannot use `USE <dbName>` in the same batch as another command.  I'd suggest closing the connection after you create the DB, and then re-open it specifying the new DB in the connection string.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - your movin sql page is hosed.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I tried on SQL Server 2008 R2 and it's working, do you have any reference that this cannot be used in the same connection ?

Comment: @Lai32290 can you write any thing more about how is this not working ? Does it connect to db ?

Comment: @AntonioBakula Oops, my bad.  Apparently the restriction is only that it cannot be used in a *stored* batch (like a stored procedure).  Wow, I've had that wrong for years ...

Comment: @AntonioBakula Hello Antonio! I'm so sorry, again! I think it was not work, because server local, can't be "localhost", need is "Lai-PC\SQLEXPRESS", so it is working!!